# Icons on top of footer background-image

Tags: html, css, image, background, footer

I'm in the process of learning but I have a problem. I have a footer done with the background-image in css, made into a link. Used text-indent: -9999px; to get rid of the H1 on top of the footer image. I was told to write the h1 in there to be semantically correct so search engines still see it. And then hide it with the text-indent. I want to put four social media icons on top of that footer that are clickable as a link. I keep getting stuck.

```
<footer id="footer">
   <section id="socialmedia">

       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BenoitBelgium">
                <img src="../images/facebook.png" width="56" height="54" alt="Facebook icon" title="Go to Facebook."  />
       </a>

       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/brilliantben">
                <img src="../images/pinterest.png" width="54" height="54" alt="Pinterest icon" title="Go to Pinterest"  />
       </a>



       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BenoitBelgium">
                <img src="../images/twitter.png" width="54" height="54" alt="Twitter icon" title="Go to Twitter."  />
       </a>

       <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BenoitBelgium">
                <img src="../images/behance.png" width="55" height="54" alt="Behance icon" title="Go to Behance."  />
       </a>

   </section>

        <h1><a href="#">Goodbye, feel free to follow</a></h1>
</footer>
```

And this is my CSS.

```
#footer {
    background-image: url(../images/footer.png);
    height:214px;
    width: 960px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

}

#footer a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height:214px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;


}
```

[This is the footer I am trying to make.](http://tinypic.com/r/4kjnk6/5)

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `text-indent: -9999px;`? What text do you want to get rid of?

Comment: I am using it to get rid of the H1 on top of the footer image. I was told to write the h1 in there to be semantically correct so search engines still see it. And then hide it with the text-indent.

Comment: That's actually against search engines' TOS. You can't put an element in there just for the search engine, and hide it from everybody else.

Comment: Ok, git rid of it. Positioned the icons and they are clickable links. Is there a way to make the rest of the footer background-image another link? If I try to link it, the icons jump and get messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It is the `text-indent` which makes the images invisible. Remove it.

```
#footer a {
    height:214px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your icon links in css - you need one for each icon

.facebook a:link {
    width: 214px;
    height: add height here
    margin-right: 15px;
    display:block;
    background:transparent url('../images/facebook.png')center bottom no-repeat;
        background-size:25px 25px;

### }

Put this div in you footer where you want it.

Repeat sets for other Icons

Answer (score 0):

Matewka is right just remove the text-indent. You only need that to remove text you don't want to show on the site, but you want it there for seo bots to see.